# How to duplicate every key in php array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

How to add an duplicate array that after every items in array parent, the same array item is added.

The array is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zero
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
        )
        
)
```

Result expectation :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => zero
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => zero
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
        )

)
```

Please provide me with the proper code. Any help will be appreciated <3

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why not `$array = array_merge($array, $array);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$originalarray = ["zero","one","two"];
$newarray = [];

foreach($originalarray as $key=>$val){
    array_push($newarray,$val);
    array_push($newarray,$val);
}

print_r( $newarray);
```

?